# Defining additional view types

Tags: sapui5

SAP is saying in the documentation on MVC that there can be new View types created. But inspecting the source code I found that `sap.ui.core.mvc.View` is checking the ViewType by:

```
...
if (V.type === sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.Template) {
    a = new sap.ui.core.mvc.TemplateView(V);
} else {
    throw new Error("Unknown view type "+V.type+" specified.");
}
```

So it was throwing an error for any other view type. From my understanding I would need to extend the View class to use additional ViewTypes but this was bad style. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you give some more details on what you are planning to do. Evtl. you got something wrong with Views and ViewTypes?

Comment: can you put the code to show how exactly you are defining your custom view?

Answer (score 0):

As per SAPUI5 documentation,for defining other or custom view types, you need to extend the base class **sap.ui.core.mvc.View**. [More Details here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f27e3e6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

And this is only recommended way I see.

Using [sap.ui.core.mvc.view.TemplareView](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.TemplateView.html) means you are extending `sap.ui.core.mvc.View`

PS: I am not sure why you are saying extending the view as a bad style here.